# How to load data to spinner with id and name

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a table Facilities with field FacilityID and field FacilityName. I have a spinner load data to SQLite.

```
private void loadSpinnerDataHama() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseSpinner db = new DatabaseSpinner(getApplicationContext()); 
    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spin2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Facibilities;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

I have a Company form for users enter the information of company such as: Company ID, Company Name, Address, Phone, Facility,...and a 'Create' button. In Facility field I use spinner to display FacilityName, when users click on Create button, I want save FacilityID into the table Company

Comment: Used `CustomArrayAdapter`

Comment: Can u help me solved it?

Comment: what you want exactly bcz question says `How to load data to spinner with id and name` and question content says `I want when users click on Create button it will save FacilityID into table Company`

Comment: @bharat I just edit my question sorry about it not clear

Comment: Use `SimpleAdapter` and Map list with `id` and `name` but for spinner display only name. Whenever item selected you can get both values `id` and `name` in onItemSelectedListener using selected position.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

1) Declare a public String variable 'id' to store selected id;

2) save the ids in a seperate arraylist.

3) Inside the spinner.OnitemSelectedListener->

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    id=ids.get(position);
                }


            });
```

3) inside create button onclick method pass the variable named id.

Comment: separate arraylist? Are you kidding? Don'y you think it would be hard to manage separate array list? What if I delete one item from one array list and forget to delete the same indexed item from another list?

Comment: @PareshMayani it's not an issue you will delete an item from arraylist programatically right?You can easily manage to delete the same item from second array also there using position.If it's not ok go with custom adapter for filling the spinner and use gettersetter methods to store ids and set ids value as setId of  view inside the getview method;

Answer (score 0):

To manage such a data set, what you can do is:

1. Declare a `Faculty` class with faculty ID and faculty name.
2. Query the database and prepare an Arraylist with all the faculty objects, like `ArrayList<Faculty>`.
3. You can get the particular faculty data with the index/position of the selected item.

Comment: Can you help me more detail

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new Class such as Data  with two feild like id and label also the getter and setter for it.

```
class Data {
private String id;
private String label;

//create getter and setter for above properties.


}
```

Then do some changes in getAllLabels method such as:

```
  public List<Data> getAllLabels(){
    List<Data> lstData = new ArrayList<Data>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Facibilities;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
Data data = new Data();
        do {
            data .setId(add(cursor.getString(1)))
 data .setLabel(add(cursor.getString(2)));
lstData.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning data object with id and labels
    return lstData;}
```

then create one list of String labels and id from returned list:

```
List <String> labels= new ArrayList<String>();
List <String> ids= new ArrayList<String>();
foreach(data in lstData){
ids.add(data.getId());
labels.add(data.getLabel());
}
```

and then pass the lables list to the adapter and onSelect of adapter item you will get the id from it from its position:

```
spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(    AdapterView<?> parent,    View view,    int pos,    long id){

      // you will get  your id here of selected item and then you can use it         //wherever you want
      String singleId= id.get(position);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(    AdapterView<?> parent){
      Log.d(TAG,"Nothing selected ");
      selectedCurrency=-1;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Why to create an arraylist for the IDs , where as we can take the whole object from the ArrayList itself!

Comment: Do you mean ArrayList <Data> ?

Comment: Yup it is, because that list already contains all the details, so just need to get the object from particular position, based on the index of selected item!

Comment: By seeing the code posted in question I hope that @Duc Tho Pham willget confused so thats why I was using separate ArrayList. Also if you will not write any code to delete the item at particular index  so it will not create any problem. because there is no requirement  of deletion write now.